# Get Product Rating count using join in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have two tables One stores Product and the other one Rating and reviews of all the batches,
There is a column named Batch No. in Product Table. I have to show all the products in the table sorted by batch no. and each batch no should get count of reviews.

> Product Table

```
id    Product Name    Price    Batch No
```

> Reviews

```
id    Batch No    Reviews    Rating
```

I want output something like this:

```
Product Name       Price   Batch No        
Product 1           200      121
Product 2           300      121
Review Count        2
Product 1           200      125
Product 2           300      125
Review Count        3
```

I have written following query but it is not working :

```
$this->db->select('*,COUNT(reviews.id) AS Total')->from('product_table as product')->join('reviews as reviews', 'product.batch_no=reviews.batch_no')->get()->result();
```

Comment: so what the issue ? And if you getting all the product then instead of `join` use another query inside php`forEach` to get `review count`

Comment: Here i'm getting reviews count as a whole such as if there are four reviews in a table  i get four as a count but what i want is to get total according to batch no.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `Group by` and it will work

```
        $this->db->select('*, COUNT(r.id) AS Total');
        $this->db->group_by('p.batch_no');
        $this->db->join('reviews r', 'r.batch_no = p.batch_no');
        $data = $this->db->get('product_table p')->result_array();

        print_r($data);
```

Comment: But using group by i can't get seperate record of every batch no.

Comment: if duplicate then use another query to get `count`

Comment: It is duplicate

Comment: so dont join when you get product. step 1.  get product , and inside for loop of PHP use another query to find count based on that batch no.

Comment: once try with grouping with `r.bach` no instead of `p.batch no`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read this.
https://codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/results.html

To optimize SQL input

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
   foreach ($query->result() as $row)
   {
      echo $row->title;
      echo $row->name;
      echo $row->body;
   }
}
```

as for the SQL syntax, use this:

```
SELECT p.id    , p.product_name  , p.Price , r.batch_no, r.reviews
FROM product as p
      LEFT JOIN reviews as r  
        ON r.batch_no = p.batch_no
GROUP BY p.id , r.batch_no
```

Too much dependency on ACTIVE RECORDS is not a healthy thing. It has advantages for simple or less complex queries.